# Как получить переменную типа Class из Field?

Tags: java, классы, рефлексия

У меня есть некий класс. В нём есть 2 переменные указывающие на класс.

```
public class GetMe {
   public static GetMe INSTANCE;
   public static NewClassLoader classLoader;

   public GetMe(){
      INSTANCE = new GetMe();
      classLoader = new NewClassLoader();
   }
   ...
}
```

Я гружу JavaAgent в JVM и получаю Field из класса `GetMe`.
Как мне получить класс на который переменная указывает?
Те. Получаем `INSTANCE`, затем получаем classLoader из `INSTANCE`.
Как это релизовать? (Через рефлексию).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

`INSTANSE.getClass().getName();`

Comment: В этом случае получается класс - java.lang.reflect.Field.

Comment: @NanoN, правильно, нужно же класс получить